# ASP.NET MVC app not browsing to pages only Index.aspx on root

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC 1.0 app just setup  but it only shows the Index.aspx page
of Home.

Seems like the routing engine is not being engaged.

I get a 404 error when i try to browse other pages.

Any ideas why this might be?

Malcolm

Comment: On what server are you running your application? How do your routes look like?

Comment: Are you deploying this on IIS6 by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably that the ASP.NET DLL isn't being called for your request. If you are talking about IIS, [Phil Haack has a great article](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) on how to sort it out. Note: Scroll down for .* version :)

Essentially, you are telling IIS that for every extension, it should look use the .NET DLL to run it, but don't check to see if the file exists first (because in MVC, the files don't exist).